# Is it Possible to Bypass CDN to Access Source of Truth?

Tags: cdn

Developing an application to access information in race-like conditions - at a specifc time.  Referring to Akamai.  My understanding of CDN is that servers will cache data and may refresh this data after "local" client requests.  I've used `dig +trace` to see the levels of DNS servers.

Background: In tests, using a VPN, entering the world wide web from different cities, I am seeing the data come from various different Akamai servers. The data is dynamic and so the CDN must go back for the source, adding precious seconds.

I read a blog post where the source server could be effectively hidden.

Thus the question: Is it possible to bypass CDN serving and connect directly to the true source host?

Comment: Its up the the person managing the server. They sure can offer low latency access at the origin or elsewhere, but usually that would be conflicting with the goal of setting up the CDN in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to bypass CDN serving and connect directly to the true source host?

That depends on the configuration of the source.

A sophisticated setup can  prevent such direct requests from succeeding and will only allow direct access by the CDN, not by other clients.

A more naive setup will allow direct requests.